# Git Rebase Lost Everything

Tags: git, github

I tried to rebase off my development branch using

```
git rebase origin/development
```

I had a lot of merge conflicts due to the device i was using not being updated for a while. I solved all the conflicts and while i did this i also cleaned up about 90% of the project to remove all old/bad code and methods. I then did the following:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Removed old code"
git push origin/development
```

When i did this i scrolled up and remembered that i was mid rebase, so i did

```
git rebase --abort
```

To abort it, when i did this it reverted all my work back to what it was prior to me cleaning it up. I know that with git if you commit something, whether you push it or not, it isn't lost for a while. I looked at the repo and i can't see that commit anywhere, yet it said that it pushed successfully... Is there any way i can retrieve that commit?

Thanks,
Erouax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `git reflog`, it gives a history of SHA's, you can checkout to whichever SHA value you want.